# How do I make a footnote rule RTL in eledmac?

Tags: footnotes, right-to-left, eledmac, bidi

In eledmac, how do I get the the footnote rule to be RTL, i.e. to begin at the right margin, as opposed to the left? I am using polyglossia and the bidi packages with Memoir, and eledmac for its critical edition apparatus. Below is an example demonstrating the problem. Notice:

- the regular LaTeX/Memoir footnote correctly implements the invoked `\rightfootnoterule`
- the two footnote commands specific to eledmac -- `\footnoteA` and `\edtext{...}{\Afootnote{...}}` do not implement the `\rightfootnoterule` command.

I'd be grateful for any help.

```
\TeXXeTstate=1

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[series={A}]{eledmac}
\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\usepackage{bidi}

\newfontfamily{\arabicfont}[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2,WordSpace=1.66]{Arial Unicode MS}    

\rightfootnoterule

%%% DOCUMENT %%%

\begin{document}

\beginnumbering
\pstart

 بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم وصلى الله على سيدنا محمد وآله وصحبه وسلم الحمد لله المتفرد بالملك والملكوت . المتوحد بالعظمة والجبروت . 
\footnote{هذه تعليقة.}
  يحي ويميت وهو حي لا يموت . وصلى الله وسلم على سيدنا محمد سيد السابقين والآخرين ورضي الله عن الصحابة والتابعين . وتابعيهم بإحسان إلى يوم الدين . وبعد فهذه الورقات سميتها .  بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم وصلى الله على سيدنا محمد وآله وصحبه وسلم الحمد لله المتفرد بالملك والملكوت . المتوحد بالعظمة والجبروت.
\footnoteA{هذه تعليقة.}
  يحي ويميت وهو حي لا يموت . وصلى الله وسلم على سيدنا محمد سيد السابقين والآخرين ورضي الله عن الصحابة والتابعين . وتابعيهم بإحسان إلى يوم الدين . وبعد فهذه الورقات سميتها . 
بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم وصلى الله على سيدنا محمد وآله وصحبه وسلم الحمد لله المتفرد بالملك والملكوت . المتوحد بالعظمة والجبروت.
\edtext{هذه تعليقة}{\Afootnote{هذه تعليقة طويلة}}
  يحي ويميت وهو حي لا يموت .

\pend
\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `\rightfootnoterule` from `bidi` package .

Comment: Thank you for your suggest, Salim. Unfortunately, there seems to be some type of conflict (bug?) between \rightfootnoterule from the bidi package, and between eledmac. I should have included a MWE above, demonstrating this, which I will now add.

Comment: There is no support from `bidi` to `eledmac`. you should redefine `footnoterules` manually.

Comment: Thank you. I have posted a request on the ledmac Github site. It seems that eledmac already recognised when to switch the bracket of the lemma in light of RTL, so perhaps the ability to implement bidi's footnote rules (or to achieve the same results) might be added? 

In the meantime, if there are any suggestions as to how I can achieve the desired effect by manually redefining footnoterules, I'd be grateful, as my amateur attempts have not succeeded. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a partial solution for your case (awaiting the final solution, which can be used in all situations), we modify the definition of  `\footnoteruleA` and `\Afootnoterule` with :

```
\makeatletter
\let\footnoteruleA=\right@footnoterule
\let\Afootnoterule=\right@footnoterule
\makeatother
```

The command `\right@footnoterule` from `bidi` draw an RTL footenoterule, and your code becomes:

```
\TeXXeTstate=1

\documentclass[11pt,a4paperlatex]{memoir}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\DisemulatePackage{setspace}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[series={A}]{eledmac}

\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\usepackage{bidi}

\newfontfamily{\arabicfont}[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2,WordSpace=1.66]{Amiri-Regular}


\makeatletter
\let\footnoteruleA=\right@footnoterule
\let\Afootnoterule=\right@footnoterule
\makeatother

\rightfootnoterule

%%% DOCUMENT %%%

\begin{document}



\beginnumbering
\pstart



 بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم وصلى الله على سيدنا محمد وآله وصحبه وسلم الحمد لله المتفرد بالملك والملكوت. المتوحد بالعظمة والجبروت. 
\footnote{هذه تعليقة.}
  يحي ويميت وهو حي لا يموت . وصلى الله وسلم على سيدنا محمد سيد السابقين والآخرين ورضي الله عن الصحابة والتابعين . وتابعيهم بإحسان إلى يوم الدين . وبعد فهذه الورقات سميتها .  بسم الله الرحم الرحيم وصلى الله على سيدنا محمد وآله وصحبه وسلم الحمد لله المتفرد بالملك والملكوت . المتوحد بالعظمة والجبروت .
\footnoteA{هذه تعليقة.}
  يحي ويميت وهو حي لا يموت . وصلى الله وسلم على سيدنا محمد سيد السابقين والآخرين ورضي الله عن الصحابة والتابعين . وتابعيهم بإحسان إلى يوم الدين . وبعد فهذه الورقات سميتها . 
بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم وصلى الله على سيدنا محمد وآله وصحبه وسلم الحمد لله المتفرد بالملك والملكوت . المتوحد بالعظمة والجبروت .
\edtext{هذه تعليقة}{\Afootnote{هذه تعليقة طويلة}}
  يحي ويميت وهو حي لا يموت .


\pend
\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

Which gives

[image]

Comment: Excellent! That does the job, indeed. Many thanks. When you say that this is a partial solution, do you mean simply that it is something that needs to be built into eledmac, or something else?

Comment: For example the above code does not give the result in  case of  two columns footnote.

Comment: Makes sense. I've flagged this up with the eledmac maintainer, Maieul. I do have another question, building upon this solution, which I have posted [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255166/how-do-i-make-a-rtl-footnote-in-eledmac-in-the-paragraph-style). I'd be most grateful if you have any ideas over there as well, @salim.