# How do I make a RTL footnote in eledmac in the paragraph-style?

Tags: footnotes, right-to-left, eledmac, bidi

In a [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255087/how-do-i-make-a-footnote-rule-rtl-in-eledmac/255149?noredirect=1#comment610320_255149), Salim Bou helpfully provided a solution to getting RTL footnote rules in eledmac. Building on this, I wish to ask now to typeset a critical apparatus series as one paragraph. When RTL is not being used, this is easily achieved with \footparagraph{A} (for footnote series A). However, when this is done in the context of RTL, the following problem occurs:

[image]

Namely, the text is indeed in paragraph formative, but (a) the whole footnote is running LTR, and (b) the lemma is LTR.

Here is the MWE:

```
\TeXXeTstate=1

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[series={A,B}]{eledmac}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\usepackage{bidi}

%%% FONTS %%%

\newfontfamily{\arabicfont}[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2,WordSpace=1.66]{Amiri-Regular}
\newfontfamily{\englishfont}[Scale=1]{Baskerville 10 Pro}

\newenvironment{arabik}{%
    \begin{Spacing}{2}\setRTL\arabicfont}{\unsetRTL\end{Spacing}}{}

%%% ELEDMAC %%%

\fnpos{critical-familiar}
\footparagraph{A}

\makeatletter
\let\footnoteruleA=\right@footnoterule
\let\Afootnoterule=\right@footnoterule
\makeatother
\rightfootnoterule

\newcommand{\aie}[1]{\RLE{\arabicfont{#1}}} % Arabic-in-English

\newcommand{\VAR}[2]{\edtext{#1}{\Afootnote{\aie{#2}}}}
\lemmaseparator[A]{[}

\newcommand{\NOTE}[1]{\footnoteB{#1}}

\newenvironment{eledarab}[1]{\beginnumbering \pstart \begin{arabik}}{\end{arabik} \pend \endnumbering}

%%% DOCUMENT %%%

\begin{document}

\begin{eledarab}
 بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم وصلى الله على سيدنا محمد وآله وصحبه وسلم الحمد لله المتفرد بالملك والملكوت . المتوحد بالعظمة والجبروت . يحي ويميت وهو حي لا يموت . وصلى الله وسلم على سيدنا محمد سيد السابقين والآخرين ورضي الله عن الصحابة والتابعين . وتابعيهم بإحسان إلى يوم الدين . وبعد فهذه الورقات سميتها . بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم وصلى الله على سيدنا محمد وآله وصحبه وسلم الحمد لله المتفرد بالملك والملكوت .المتوحد بالعظمة والجبروت .
\NOTE{This is a note in English.}
  يحي ويميت وهو حي لا يموت . وصلى الله وسلم على سيدنا محمد سيد السابقين والآخرين ورضي الله عن الصحابة والتابعين . وتابعيهم بإحسان إلى يوم الدين .
\VAR{هذه تعليقة}{هذه تعليقة طويلة}
   وبعد فهذه الورقات سميتها . بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم وصلى الله على سيدنا محمد وآله وصحبه وسلم الحمد لله المتفرد بالملك والملكوت . المتوحد بالعظمة والجبروت .
\VAR{هذه تعليقة ثانية}{هذه تعليقة ثانية طويلة}
  يحي ويميت وهو حي لا يموت .
\end{eledarab}

\end{document}
```

Please note that the main language has been set as English; thus, my custom command \aie so that text can run RTL when the environment is LTR. (This is intentional, as it replicates the production environment.)

I imagine that the solution lies in redefining the footnote series, or perhaps the lemma, with some commands from bidi, but I wasn't able to figure out. I'd be grateful for help.

Comment: Can you post an MWE which produce the above image so  we can use it to solve the problem

Comment: Of course, it is now in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If the mainlanguage of the your document is set to arabic you can get what you meant with some customizations for `\footnoteruleB` and  `\footnoteB`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[series={A,B}]{eledmac}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}

%%% FONTS %%%

\newfontfamily{\arabicfont}[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2,WordSpace=1.66]{Amiri-Regular}
\newfontfamily{\englishfont}{Baskerville 10 Pro}

\newenvironment{arabik}{%
    \begin{Spacing}{2}\setRTL\arabicfont}{\unsetRTL\end{Spacing}}{}

%%% ELEDMAC %%%

\fnpos{critical-familiar}
\footparagraph{A}

\makeatletter
\let\footnoteruleA=\right@footnoterule
\let\Afootnoterule=\right@footnoterule
\let\footnoteruleB=\left@footnoterule
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\footnoteB}[1]{\LTRfootnote{#1}}

\newcommand{\aie}[1]{\RLE{\arabicfont{#1}}} % Arabic-in-English

\newcommand{\VAR}[2]{\edtext{#1}{\Afootnote{\aie{#2}}}}
\lemmaseparator[A]{]}

\newcommand{\NOTE}[1]{\footnoteB{\englishfont{#1}}}

\newenvironment{eledarab}[1]{\beginnumbering \pstart \begin{arabik}}{\end{arabik} \pend \endnumbering}

%%% DOCUMENT %%%

\begin{document}

\begin{eledarab}

 بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم وصلى الله على سيدنا محمد وآله وصحبه وسلم الحمد لله المتفرد بالملك والملكوت . المتوحد بالعظمة والجبروت . يحي ويميت وهو حي لا يموت . وصلى الله وسلم على سيدنا محمد سيد السابقين والآخرين ورضي الله عن الصحابة والتابعين . وتابعيهم بإحسان إلى يوم الدين . وبعد فهذه الورقات سميتها . بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم وصلى الله على سيدنا محمد وآله وصحبه وسلم الحمد لله المتفرد بالملك والملكوت .المتوحد بالعظمة والجبروت .
\NOTE{This is a note in English.}
  يحي ويميت وهو حي لا يموت . وصلى الله وسلم على سيدنا محمد سيد السابقين والآخرين ورضي الله عن الصحابة والتابعين . وتابعيهم بإحسان إلى يوم الدين .
\VAR{هذه تعليقة}{هذه تعليقة طويلة}
   وبعد فهذه الورقات سميتها . بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم وصلى الله على سيدنا محمد وآله وصحبه وسلم الحمد لله المتفرد بالملك والملكوت . المتوحد بالعظمة والجبروت .
\VAR{هذه تعليقة ثانية}{هذه تعليقة ثانية طويلة}
  يحي ويميت وهو حي لا يموت .
\end{eledarab}

\end{document}
```

Note that  `fontspec` and `bidi` are both loaded with `polyglossia` so you can avoid refer to them in your code.
[image]

Comment: That is helpful, thank you. However, it has some problems. It removes footnoteB from eledmac's ordering of the footnote streams (i.e. \fnpos{critical-familiar} is ignored, so \footnoteB is being placed above \AfFootnote. More problematically, my original question asks whether it is possible to get the Arabic footnotes RTL when English is the main language, because this critical edition comes as part of a book in English. These two things prevent me from adopting this, as is, as an answer.

Comment: In this case you should patch the command `\footparagraph` for RTL mode, good luck ;)

Comment: Thank you, salim. If I knew how, I would have done so already. :-) But thank you for all of your help thus far, all the same. Hopefully @maieul or someone else might be able to advise.